# 404 and 500 error in wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Tags: wordpress, server, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-500

My website was working fine until yesterday. today on wards when i load a specific page which contains `tabs,  Masonry Media Grid and 
 two post grids which is added via Visual Composer` 
 i am experiencing the following problems

1. sometimes i am getting 500 internal server error in browser.
2. Sometimes Masonry Media Grid and two post grids are not loading
3. Sometimes  two post grids are not loading
4. Sometimes  one post grids is not loading 
   and getting error in console

> 3/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error
>
> /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Is this problem related to server issues
I am not able to find the problem. Anyone please help me.